# What causes these brown ruaty spots on my hardy kiwi plant?

Tags: diagnosis

I have noticed my kiwi got some brown leaves. It's on the front side of the leaf, back or both. Recently I have moved it to sunnier location could that be it? there is no sign or any creatures.[image: brown rusty spots on hardy kiwi plant]